# how convert char to int and assign to other object in java

Tags: java

when i convert char to int and assigned in different variable of cell object
  but one value assigned as 0 other is assigned as ascii value.

```
class Cell {
    public Cell() {}

    public Cell(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }

    public int row;
    public int col;
}
Cell makeCell(String str) {
        char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
        Cell cell = new Cell();
        cell.row = ch[1] - 1; ** <--- cell.row assigned 0**
        cell.col = ch[0] - 'A'; ** <--- cell.col assigned 48 but why?**
        return cell;
}
public static void main(String arg[]){
Cell cell = makeCell("A1");
}
```

Comment: What did you expect and why?

Comment: Please tell us more about why you need to subtract both a number and a character from your `char[]`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when executing your code, the value `48` was assigned to `cell.row` and not to `cell.col`.

It's like that, because of the ASCII value of `'1'`, which is not `1`, but `49`:

```
cell.row = ch[1] - 1;
```

Will be equal to:

```
cell.row = 49 - 1;
```

which makes it clear that the result of `49 -1` will be 48.

Whereas with the other:

```
cell.col = ch[0] - 'A';
```

It will be equal to:

```
cell.col = 65 - 65;
```

Because the ASCII value of `'A'` is `65`.

---

I am not really sure what you're trying to acomplish with your code but if you want it to "work" you need to change the `1` to a `'1'`

Answer (score 1):

'1' is 49 as int value. And if you subtract 1 from it than result will be 48.
But 'A' is 65 and you are subtracting 'A' as int from it and the result is 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.row = ch[1] - 1; <--- cell.row assigned 0
cell.col = ch[0] - 'A'; <--- cell.col assigned 48 but why?
```

The Ascii values of the characters are stored in int values.